# how do I reload the data in UiSearchDisplayController and Tableview after modific data?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

where search data and click item, a new view appears, where I can change the data. If change data and return to uisearchdisplaycontroller, data not reload (also in tableView). How do i reload data?

sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UITableView Class has a method called `reloadData` which can be called and it reloads all of your tableView's rows. [UITableView Class Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_60)

If you only need to reload specific rows you can use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` passing in an array of `NSIndexPath` and a row animation.

You can also reload entire sections using `reloadSections:withRowAnimation:`.